# Why is kotlin.jvm package accessible in commonMain for Kotlin multi-platform project?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

I see that for a multi-platform Kotlin project, you can access `Kotlin.jvm` package in the commonMain.

For example, I could use (without any compilation error) `kotlin.jvm.Synchronized`

commonMain is shared by all platforms, does this mean for iOS platform `kotlin.jvm.Synchronized` would work fine? If yes, then why is it under a jvm package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would do nothing on iOS, but it allows you to add that annotation in common code without needing to do something complex with expect/actual. It would obviously be pointless in Kotlin/JS (single-threaded).